# Javascript / amcharts - dynamically control property value of amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, amcharts

I am trying to mildly replicate what amcharts has done to their  demo chart in [this link](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/) ie. adding controls to change the graph's property. But I can't figure out how the value updating works in javascript. Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<body>
...
<div id="chartdiv" style="width=100%; height:400px;"></div>
<input type="range" min="0.1" max="1.0" value="0.5" step="0.01" id="mySlider">
...
</body>
```

**Javascript/amCharts**:

```
<script>
// data for amCharts
var chartData = [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 4252
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }];

// drawing amCharts using object-based method
AmCharts.ready( function() {
  //var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv");
  var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.categoryField = "country";

  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.valueField = "visits";
  graph.type = "column";
  graph.fillAlphas = updateValue();
  chart.addGraph( graph );

  chart.write("chartdiv")
});

// here is my function to update value dynamically
function updateValue() {
    val = document.getElementById("mySlider").value;
    return val;
}
</script>
```

I want to update the opacity of the graph dynamically. How do I do that? This should be simple but I am quite new in javascript development.

EDIT: Updating with the final code which works

**Javascript/amCharts**:

```
<script>
...
// drawing amCharts using object-based method
AmCharts.ready( function() {
  //var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv");
  var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.categoryField = "country";

  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
  graph.valueField = "visits";
  graph.type = "column";
  graph.fillAlphas = updateValue();
  chart.addGraph( graph );

  chart.write("chartdiv");

  //add this code to add dynamic opacity control
  //** "jquery.js" script needs to be linked **//
  $('#mySlider').on('input change', function() {
      //var target = chart;
      //chart.startDuration = 0;           
      var target = chart.graphs[0]
      target['fillAlphas'] = this.value;
      chart.validateNow();
  });

});
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code on change event of your input

```
    jQuery('#mySlider').off().on('input change', function() {
        var target = chart;
        chart.startDuration = 0;
        target = chart.graphs[0];
        target['fillAlphas'] = this.value;
        chart.validateNow();
    });
```

Comment: This works for me although I wonder what's the use of `.off()` and the first 2 lines `var target = chart; chart.startDuration = 0;`? I manage to make the dynamic changes work without those lines/codes.